# Opportunity Access for customer community and customer community licenses

Tags: customer-portal, opportunity

I can't show opportunity tab to customer community and customer community licenses users. And on the profile level there is no any option for this.

I read the documents and type of licenses and according to them opportunity is not available for user which these type of licenses.

But here I've two doubts

1) Here I have a controller and apex page. In controller I can get all the opportunities and all fetched opportunities are saved in wrapper class and then using a this wrapper class I can show opportunity and it is running successfully.

2) Here I have a controller and apex page. In controller I can get all the opportunities and saved in list and this list is a type of opportunity eg `List<Opportunity> x`. When I try to display oppty (using X) I got exception.

I am access my apex page from community portal.

My question if opportunity is not accessible to Customer portal and C Portal Licenses user the how can controller fetch the opportunities data ans show through the wrapper class and not opportunity type list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question lies in the nature of a wrapper class. The wrapper class appears to Apex and the Community as an Object of Type that's something other than an Object that's of Type Opportunity. The class does not extend the Opportunity class nor is it an instance of Opportunity. So until you try to display a list of Type Opportunity, SF doesn't recognize that your wrapper class contains information that's not allowed to be displayed in your Customer Community.

In short, you might also say that its the same as permissions and sharing rules being applied at the time of display on a VF page. Its a simple case where Customer Community users don't have permission to view Opportunities because their license doesn't allow it.

The only way around this is to create a mirror object with Opportunities using a trigger to keep the object in sync. You can then display your custom mirror object records to your Customer Community Users. Otherwise, you'll need to purchase Partner Community Licenses.

Comment: If Salesforce not recognize the instance is a opportuinty or not, But SF can recognize the data is being fetched from opportunity object and user is belong to C Portal. Is it a Bug?

Comment: The wrapper isn't declared as an instance of Opportunity. It declared as it's own Type, so no, I wouldn't see it as a bug. SF's security is working as intended by preventing the Opportunity Object Type from being displayed in a Customer Portal/Community. I don't recall reading any docs indicating a class would be prevented from "fetching" Opportunity records, instead only from allowing CRUD on them from **inside** the portal/community by users with that license.

Comment: Hi, But I can perform CURD operation on Opportunity records, If Opportunity object is not available for C-Portal, Then I can understand that we can fetch the data but can't show by using opportunity instance instead of this we have to use wrapper classes to bind the data with VFPages. But confusion is that if opportunity is not available of C-portal user then how can we perform CURD. It is necessary for me to know that because I have a project in which I need Opportunity object for C-portal user. So It would be great if I have all info then I can tell to my client that what we can do.

Comment: Read the final paragraph of my answer. The only way to access Opportunity is to create a custom mirror object of Opportunity using a trigger that syncs data to it (and another that syncs back if needed). I have successfully done this myself in a community.

Comment: Thanks I read you final paragraph but I was thinking that if use opportunity object in C-Portal and Salesforce denied any thing to do on this than all project get vanish. And thanks for your help.