# How to expose opportunity object in a community

Tags: community, customer-community, community-cloud

We are creating a new community for our grantees.

We are managing the grantee information in the `opportunity` object.

So each grantee has an `opportunity` record and we want him to be able to manage his `opportunity` through the community.

We want to use the `Customer Community Logins` user licenses for our grantees, because they are reasonably priced.

But the `opportunity` object is not viable with that license [according to this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0&language=en_US#fntarg_9).

So our question is:

**What is the best way to expose the opportunity to the community?**

I can think of 2 ways:

1. Buy the very expensive "Partner Community Logins" user license (this is too expensive to my company so not a real viable solution).
2. Develop a lightning component / VF page to show and manage the opportunity.

Is there another way?

What is the best way to implement that?

What are the pros / cons?

Any info would be highly appreciated!

Thanks, Itai

**EDIT**

This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45736/opportunity-access-for-customer-community-and-customer-community-licenses) question because they are not the same - I am asking for a workaround and what is the best approach for a solution and I know the `opportunity` is not accessible for the customer community license, while the other question asks if this is true...

Also the answer there is not good enough as I am searching for a better workaround.

Comment: The solution of a "mirror object" looks for me VERY bad, a better solution would be to use the other object and replace the opportunity (I do not need the extra CRM functionality of the opportunity) and not mirror it to the opportunity. The second solution that I offered is to develop a UI of my own only for the opportunity list and view and edit modes. What do you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to tackle this

1.Create a custom object to mimic Opportunity object fields and functionality and use that instead of Opportunity. In short not using opportunity object
2.Create a simple form in UI and use a mirror object of opportunity and keep both in sync through trigger as mentioned by [Opportunity Access for customer community and customer community licenses](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45736/opportunity-access-for-customer-community-and-customer-community-licenses)

My personal opinion of 2 is that its kind of back door entry to Opportunity object for community license. Not sure what contractual implications it has if salesforce finds it out.

For our project we ended up buying Partner community logins to stay compliant to it.

Comment: The solution of a "mirror object" looks for me VERY bad, a better solution would be to use the other object and replace the opportunity (I do not need the extra CRM functionality of the opportunity) and not mirror it to the opportunity. The second solution that I offered is to develop a UI of my own only for the opportunity list and view and edit modes. What do you think about that?

Comment: Developing UI of your own with a mirror object or a custom object?

Comment: with the standard opportunity object

Comment: you would have to give with/without sharing for your apex controller. without giving access to the opportunity object on the profile how would you access it?. If you set your class as without sharing thats like running the class in admin mode, so either ways you would end up accessing opportunity object which shouldn't be for the license you are planning to use.

Comment: Yes - I know this, and this is why I have posted the question, to see if there is a better workaround